# Whys is ajax @post empty when it reach the php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code where I attempt to post values to a php file using ajax/json. The php file throws warnings saying: Undefined index: companyid, Undefined index: companyname, Undefined index: calendar_eventStart, Undefined index: calendar_eventEnd.
I realize that the variables posted using ajax are empty when they are picked up on the server side, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

Console log:

> Data: {"companyid":1,"companyname":"Fifteen AS","calendar_eventStart":"2018-06-06T22:00:00.000Z","calendar_eventEnd":"2018-06-06T22:00:00.000Z"}

jQuery:

```
var formData = {
                    companyid,
                    companyname,
                    calendar_eventStart,
                    calendar_eventEnd
                };
                formData = (JSON.stringify(formData));
                console.log('Data: ' + formData);                   
                $.ajax({
                url: "create_calendar_event.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",   
                data:{data: formData},                   
                success: function(response) {
                alert(response);                
                }               
                });
```

PHP:

```
var_dump($_POST['companyid']);
var_dump($_POST['companyname']);
var_dump($_POST['calendar_eventStart']);
var_dump($_POST['calendar_eventEnd']);
$event_status = 'Success';
echo json_encode($event_status,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: why do you stringify formData?

Comment: just send `data: formdata`

Comment: You could also do `var_dump($_POST)` and you'll see what you're actually posting. However, if you follow @Jeff's suggestions (remove the `JSON.stringify()` row and just send `data: formData`), it should work. Currently, your're sending everything in `$_POST['data']` as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
data:{data: formData},
```

you are creating a sub-object, therefore the actual data could be found in

```
$_POST['data']['companyid'] // etc
```

IF you didn't `JSON.stringify(formData)` first. If you keep the stringify `$_POST['data']` will only contain a string containing the data. Getting that out needs another magic in php. So just remove the stringify here.

But you don't need that extra 'data' object. You could just do

```
$.ajax({
      url: "create_calendar_event.php",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",   
      data: formData, 
      success: function(response) {
           alert(response);                
      }               
});
```

final note to `JSON.stringify()`: I can't think of another situation than sending data via URI (a GET request) that would need to stringify a jsObject.

Comment: Help is highly appreciated Jeff and Magnus. I followed your advice and removed the stringify part and now it works!